# react native flashlist what is the type props in renderItem?

Tags: react-native, expo

Whats the ListRenderItem prop in flashlist?

```
  const renderItem: ListRenderItem<ICard> = ({ item }) => (
    <Card
      {...item}
    />
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ListRenderItem` is not a prop it is a **type** and it is not provided by `FlashList` but by `FlatList`. The [FlashList](https://shopify.github.io/flash-list/docs/usage) component is just a wrapper around `FlatList` and the `renderItem` functionality is identical when it comes to types.

The type `ListRenderItem` is used in `FlatList` for typing the `renderItem` callback function. It is actually a function that returns a JSX element. The type is as follows:

```js
type ListRenderItem<ItemT> = (info: ListRenderItemInfo<ItemT>) => React.ReactElement | null;
```

The generic `ItemT` is the type of the `item` (which is the type of the elements inside the `data` prop inside `FlatList`). The `ListRenderItemInfo<ItemT>` is typed as follows

```js
interface ListRenderItemInfo<ItemT> {
    item: itemT;
    index: number;
    separators: {
       highlight: () => void;
       unhighlight: () => void;
       updateProps: (select: 'leading' | 'trailing', newProps: any) => void;
    }
}
```

The `ListRenderItemInfo` is the type of the object that is passed to the `renderItem` callback. We are usually destructuring `item` and `index`. The usual example is as follows:

```js
renderItem={({item, index}) => ...}
```

That is a function which receives an object as an input parameter and we usually destructure its properties `item` and sometimes `index`. It returns a JSX element.

In summary, there is no difference for the types when it comes to `FlashList` in comparison to `FlatList`.

For your example:

```js
const renderItem: ListRenderItem<ICard> = ({ item }) ...
```

This means that your `renderItem` function receives a `ListRenderItemInfo` whose `item` is typed with `ICard`. It returns a JSX element as usual.